# Execution error in a makefile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, time, makefile, syntax-error

This is a reduced example of a makefile which illustrates my problem:

```
exec:
    time (ls > ls.txt; echo $$? > code) 2> time.txt
```

*make exec* runs fine under one Linux installation:

```
Linux-2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-6.8-Final
```

but it fails under my Ubuntu installation:

```
Linux-4.4.0-64-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
```

and produces the message:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

No problems if I run the command *time* directly from the terminal.

Are there different versions of the command in different Linux installations? I need the version which allows a sequence of commands.

Answer (score 2):

Make always invokes `/bin/sh` to run the recipe.  On some systems, `/bin/sh` is an alias for bash which has a lot of extra extensions to the standard POSIX shell (sh).  On other systems (like Ubuntu), `/bin/sh` is an alias for dash which is a smaller, simpler, closer to plain POSIX shell.

Bash has a built-in `time` operation which accepts an entire pipeline and shows the time taken for it (run `help time` at a bash shell command prompt to see documentation).  Other shells like dash don't have a built-in `time`, so when you run it you get the program `/usr/bin/time`; run `man time` to see documentation.  As a separate program it of course cannot time an entire pipeline (because a pipeline is a feature of the shell); it can only time one individual command.

You have various options:

You can force your makefile to always use bash as its shell by adding:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

to it.  I recommend adding a comment there as well describing why bash specifically is needed.

Or you can modify your rule to work in a portable way by making the shell invocation explicit so that `time` only has one command to invoke:

```
exec:
        time /bin/sh -c 'ls > ls.txt; echo $$? > code' 2>/time.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a semicolon in front of "time". As is, make is trying to parse your command as a list of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The only suggestion that worked is to force bash in my makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

I checked: on my Ubuntu machine, /bin/sh is really /bin/dash whereas on the CentOS machine it is /bin/bash!

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, the suggestion of making the shell invocation explicit did not redirect the output file to 'time.txt'.